# Can you translate this problem into mathematical terms?

Tags: notation, puzzle, mathematical-modeling, modal-logic

[image: Hi guys I wanted to solve it mathematically not mentally]

I have a word problem here, and I want to solve it mathematically not mentally.
You can check how it is mentally solved here :
https://youtu.be/mmXIJY2X5Hg
At 6:10 till 9:02

Comment: Try this: A. K. Austin, "A Calculus for Know/Don't Know Problems." *Math. Mag.* 49 (1976), no. 1, 12–14.